# How to create a Romance-based conlang?

Tags: conlang-creation, natural-languages

How unoriginal! Yet another guy creating a Romance-based conlang (especially since it's already been covered several times here). Jokes aside, as the title suggests, I'm looking to create a Romance-based conlang. I'd like to point out that I'm not that new to creating conlangs: I've already created one, it's not realistic/natural at all (plus, I didn't make it evolve from proto-fictional-languages, I just created it lol). The reason I'm telling you this is that I have NO IDEA how to create a conlang based on existing languages.

Should I research the phonology, phonotactics, orthography, syntax, grammar, vocabulary, etc. of the five "main" Romance languages (Italian, French, Spanish, Portuguese and Romanian) and mix it all up? Or should I research the phonology, phonotactics, orthography, syntax, grammar, vocabulary, etc. of Proto-Roman and/or Vulgar Latin and make them evolve in my own way so that I end up with my "own" Romance language?

If the answer is none of the above or only the latter, then can you tell me how to go about it?

Thank you in advance for answering!! :)

Comment: See also [this question and its answers for more Romance conlangs](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/q/318/142)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several approaches to this task.

One of them is in fact creating an altlang, based on an alternate history where a Romance language survived or develops in some region outside the Romania as we know it. [This answer to another question](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/a/896/142) explicitly names [Brithenig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brithenig) set in Great Britain and [Venedic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venedic_language) set in Poland. The general way of developping such a language is to start from Vulgar Latin, apply some interesting sound shifts and some borrowing from a substrate language.

Another approach is creating a Pan-Romance *lingua franca*. Starting with Peano's [Latino sine flexione](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latino_sine_flexione), there was quite a bunch of such languages, notable members of that branch are [Novial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novial), [Occidental/Interlingue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlingue) and finally [Interlingua (IALA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlingua). Interlingua enjoys quite a success as an international auxiliary language, ranking second after [Esperanto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto). Typically, such languages streamline the grammar to make it more palatable and use some eclectic selection of words from the different living Romance languages (often neglecting Romanian, by putting a strong Romanian bias in your selection you can create something fresh and new).

Other approaches are possible.